# Clear file contents if file is opened as "a" append

Tags: python

Given :

```
with open("some file path", mode="a", encoding='utf-8') as envConfig_file:
     pass
```

Is there a way to clear the whole file without opening the file again as "w"?

Comment: Why open in append mode if you don't want to keep what's already there?

Comment: Initially I do get everything from the file, then I change a bunch of stuff, and want  to rewrite to the file
I convert the content to json... change stuff... convert  to txt back and write to the file

Comment: Check the `seek` and `truncate` methods

Comment: OK, let me put this another way: why don't you want to open the file in write mode, if you want to replace what's already there?

Comment: Well thought there might be a better way then just opening the file multiple times in multiple modes

Comment: It's fair enough not to want to open the file again, you never know if that's the same file the second time

Comment: For reading and then rewriting, the more usual mode would be `r+` although either way works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `seek` and `truncate` methods.

As a side note, for reading and then rewriting, the more usual mode would be `r+`

```
with open("some file path", mode="r+", encoding='utf-8') as envConfig_file:
    ... # read the file
    envConfig_file.seek(0)
    envConfig_file.truncate()
    ... # write new contents
```